# silence the updatedAt field with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I would like to disable or silence the updatedAt field when I update a record. As per sequelize docs looks like this option was available on [v5.9.2](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases?q=silent&expanded=true).

my sequelize version: ^5.22.5

I've tried the following however it performs the update but still proceeds to update the updatedAt field in the DB.

#1

```
model.update(
        {
            count: Number(model.count) + 2, 
        },
        {
            where: {
                id: 10
            },
            silent: true
        }
    );
```

#2

```
model.increment('count', { by: 2, where: { id: 10 }, silent: true });
```

#3

```
model.save ({ silent: true })
```

Comment: How did you create a table? If you create on your DB side directly, check your DB schema. If you have auto update on the field on the DB level, `silent` cannot work.

Comment: The schema of the **updatedAt** field is the following:                                    `updatedAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Is there a way to update a row without it updating the updatedAt field with this schema?

Answer (score 1):

`silent` is the app-level functionalities not to update the `updatedAt` column, however, if you have `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, this is the DB-level automatic update on the column.

**TL;DR**

`silent` works by not passing `updatedAt` to UPDATE query. So if the DB's column doesn't have any automatic assignment, by not passing the new value for `updatedAt`, the column value should stay the same. While, if you have automatic update on the DB's column, not passing the value means it allows DB to automatically assign the new value.

**How I can do "silence" without updating DB schema**

To disable the DB's automatic field, you can pass the value that you want to assign for the column. By default, Sequelize also has an automatic assignment of `updateAt` column, so we need to overwrite it.

```
const model = sequelize.define('MyModel',
  {
    count: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  },
  {
    hooks: {
      beforeUpdate: (record, options) => {
        if(options['custom_silent']) {   // Add my custom silencing option
          // If custom_silent is true, pass previous(current value in DB) updatedAt value and assigned to it
          record.dataValues.updatedAt = record._previousDataValues.updatedAt
        }
        // If custom_silent is not true, use default Sequelize behavior (updatedAt = (current timestamp))
      }
    }
  }
)
```

**How to use it**

```
await modelInstance.update(
  { 
    count: modelInstance.count + 1000,
  },
  {
    custom_silent: true
  }
);
```

Comment: The record._previousDataValues does not have the actual previous value of the date in the beforeUpdate or the afterUpdate hook. Below are the values from the afterUpdate hook.  record.dataValues  = {id: 10, count: 1236, updatedAt: 2023-01-24T22:20:43.000Z} and  record._previousDataValues = { id: 10, count: 1234, updatedAt: 2023-01-24T22:20:43.000Z} so I won't be able to apply your suggestion. It's odd bc it has the previous value of the count but not the date.

Comment: you need to use `beforeUpdate`, that's how you intercept to generate a right SQL. `afterUpdate` is AFTER SQL is executed, so it won't make any SQL call.  Also, make sure you are not using `silent`, this will interfere with `custom_silent`.

Comment: you might also need to use model instance's method instead of model's class method.  so like `const x = await model.findByPk(10);  x.update(..., { custom_silent: true });`

Comment: Ended up altering the table and removing the ON UPDATE on the the updatedAt field.